# Not able to add dynamic data into list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add data into `li` dynamically but not able to add it.There are multiple rows of data to get added. I am getting my html markup code visible on the screen .Here is the HTML..

```
<div data-role="content">
 <ul id="ContactList">
 </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the jquery code.

```
function onSuccess(contacts) {
//console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts))
 $('#ContactList').empty();
  $.each(contacts, function(key, value) {
    if(value.name){
        $.each(value.name, function(key, value) {
           if(key == 'formatted'){
               name = value;
           }                      
        });
    }
    if(value.phoneNumbers){
        $.each(value.phoneNumbers, function(key, value) {
            phone = value.value;
        });
    }                    
    $('#ContactList').append('
    < li>< a href=" #">< h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+name+'< /h3>< div class="ui-li-desc">Club '+phone+'< /div>< /a>< /li>');

   $('#ContactList').listview();

   }
```

Comment: try using $('#ContactList').listview("refresh");

Comment: @RamzanZafar OK..Let me try ..I will inform ..

Comment: @sanatanmishra I found the problem and added the solution bellow.

Comment: @sanatanmishra did you check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/et2nLwfb/9/)? also i added screenshot of the result for jquery mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the code is missing closure brackets `)}` to the `.each` function and html tags have `<` (space) right after opening them.
try this code:[image]

```
function onSuccess(contacts) {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts))
        $('#ContactList').empty();
        $.each(contacts, function (key, value) {
            if (value.name) {
                $.each(value.name, function (key, value) {
                    if (key == 'formatted') {
                        name = value;
                    }
                });
            }
            if (value.phoneNumbers) {
                $.each(value.phoneNumbers, function (key, value) {
                    phone = value.value;
                });
            }
            $('#ContactList').append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">' + name + '</h3><div class="ui-li-desc">Club ' + phone + '</div></a></li>');
        });
        $('#ContactList').listview();
    }
```

working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/et2nLwfb/9/)

Comment: it is when you are adding elements dynamically, according to [jQuery Mobile documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh).
i think that in your case it's not.

Comment: I am sorry to tell you that its not working..I am getting same HTML Markup as output on screen..

Answer (score 1):

The Html Formating is not correct in the line where you are building the content. The html tags are broken.

Instead of:

```
$('#ContactList').append('
    < li>< a href=" #">< h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+name+'< /h3>< div class="ui-li-desc">Club '+phone+'< /div>< /a>< /li>');
```

Use the following one:

```
$('#ContactList').append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">'+name+'</h3><div class="ui-li-desc">Club '+phone+'</div></a></li>');
```

Comment: this is not the only problem.. check my solution below with jsfiddle.

Comment: @EdanFeiles The initial question stated: "I am getting my html markup code visible on the screen".
That was fixed in the provided solution.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
$('#ContactList').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out!

```
 function onSuccess(contacts) 
    {

    var h3 = $('<h3 class="ui-li-heading"></h3>');
    var div = $('<div class="ui-li-desc"></div>');
    var ac = $('<a href=" #"></a>');
    var li = $('<li></li>');

     $('#ContactList').empty();
      $.each(contacts, function(key, value) {
        if(value.name){
            $.each(value.name, function(key, value) {
               if(key == 'formatted'){
                   name = value;
               }                      
            });
        }

     if(value.phoneNumbers){
            $.each(value.phoneNumbers, function(key, value) {
                phone = value.value;

       });

     } 

         h3.html(name);
         div.html(phone);

         ac.html(h3+div);

         li.html(ac);



        $('#ContactList').append(li);
       $('#ContactList').listview('refresh');
      });
    }
```

Comment: Will this code work on jquery mobile app too?because i am using it for the same..Thanks..

Comment: Is there any change needed in the HTML mark up code that i posted in the question ?Because my isseu is same on trying all these solutions too.

Comment: Now i am able to see screen ..Previous error removed but still not able to see any data in the contact list ..Why ?I am getting (dot) [Object Object][Object Object]

Comment: @WisdmLabs @sanatan you are calling `$('#ContactList').listview('refresh');` inside the `.each` function.